# How we can cover the code coverage for multiple conditions in IF statement in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I'm trying to write a test class for below class method, but I'm not sure about how we can write tests for multiple conditions in IF statement.

Below is the class method definition :

```
public class ControllerHelper
{
    public static boolean validate (Case obj)
    {
        if((obj.field1 = 'Yes' || obj.field2 = 'Yes') && checkNullValue(obj.field3))
        ||
        ((obj.field4 = 'Yes' || obj.field5 = 'Yes') && checkNullValue(obj.field6))
       )
       return true;
       else
        {
              return false;
        }
    }

     public static boolean checkNullValue(String value)
            {
                if(value==null || value.trim().length()==0)
                {
                    return true;
                }    
                return false;
            }
}
```

I did try using Assert & AssertEquals but it's not helping me out.

Any help or suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: What do you want? 100% test coverage for these two methods?

Comment: You code is not compilable, please edit the code.

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Updated the code & not 100% but at least 75% coverage is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: You have not updated your code yet

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Sorry, i got what was wrong in the code...I have updated the code now

Comment: @NoorAShuvo you there?

Comment: yes, I am here. Whats is issue ?

Comment: @NoorAShuvo I tried ur solution, it works for first condition, and for second condition I wrote a new method but encountered issue here : isValid = ControllerHelper.validate(case1);    "The error is : attempt to de-reference a null object"

Comment: @NoorAShuvo Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with the below code, it will not cover 100%. You have to write a couple of test methods to cover all the fields and logics.

```
@isTest
public class ControllerHelperTest 
{
    @isTest
    private static void testValidate1()
    {
        ControllerHelper ctrl = new ControllerHelper();
        Boolean isValid = false;

        Test.StartTest();

        Case case1 = new Case();
        case1.field1 = 'Yes';
        case1.field2 = 'Yes';
        case1.field3 = null;

        insert case1;

        isValid = ControllerHelper.validate(case1);

        Test.stopTest();

        System.assert(isValid, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: for the second method , it is throwing error at line isValid = ControllerHelper.validate(case1); ....Error is : Attempt to de-reference a null object